# Python and SQLite3 aggregation issue

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to python and SQLite3. Currently I am working on a project but I run into a dead end. I am writing a code for row count for tables. Here is a part of my code:

```
    def button1Pressed(self):
        import sqlite3
        conn = sqlite3.connect("Xie.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("Select Count(*) from Days")
        x = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
        print"count query executed"
        print"x=",x
```

It suppose to give the x with how many rows based on the Selected Table Days. However, no matter what tables I tried, the answer is always x = 0. 
I make sure to use the primary key when I created these tables at the beginning. Thank you for everyone's time.

Comment: Are your sure DB and table name is correct. Because I just executed it and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure since I have another function, which counts the total rows for the whole table. The answer matches my table rows.

Comment: Try this `create table test(name string);` and tell me does it create a new table?

Comment: Hi, thank you for such a quick reply. Do I try it in Python or my SQLite database?

Comment: Python. In same code above.

Comment: It is not working...